# Add multi-stack axes label to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset, named “data”:

[image]

```
df=ddply(data,c("Treatment","Concentration"),summarise,mean=mean(Inhibition),sd=sd(Inhibition),n=length(Inhibition),se=sd/sqrt(n))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Treatment, y=Inhibition))

p1 <- p + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Inhibition-se,ymax=Inhibition+se), position="dodge",width=0.2)
```

and I got the following graph:

[image]

I want x-axis to be like the picture below:

[image]

How woud I do this??

Comment: Please check out my answer to see how you could better structure your question. Firstly, make sure you include a usable dataset, not just a screenshot. Also, remove any code which is not relevant to the question, for example the error bars. Hope this helps for the future

Answer (score 3):

This is best achieved using a facet within ggplot. As you haven’t included a reusable dataset, I have made one here:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B"),
           SubGroup = c(letters[1:5]),
           value = 1:5
           )
```

See below the  `facet_grid` line which has a few additional options specified. You can read more about the added arguments [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html)

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = SubGroup, value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  facet_grid(.~Group, scales = "free_x", space = "free", switch = "x") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

For your data, you will need to split the drug and dose into two separate columns first, like my example.

Comment: Great!  Appreciate it!

Comment: @sh_yang Please upvote and mark as accepted if you are happy with the answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers